# Unwanted mysql logs to get the procedure definitions

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, percona, amazon-aurora

I am using Aurora and .NET 3.5 framework in my application which is internally using .NET mysqlconnector 6.9.3 version. When I enable my general_log, I see below logs. I am looking forward a way that I can disable the same or Is this how mysql connector designed. Any thoughts around this! I use appdynamics to monitor the queries and I see that whenever there is a procedure call, there is a INFORMATION_SCHEMA calls as well. Please have a look at the below logs.

```
12 Init DB  mydatabasename
12 Query    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA LIKE 'mydatabasename' AND ROUTINE_NAME LIKE 'getUser'
12 Query    SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE `mydatabasename`.`getUser`
12 Query    CALL `mydatabasename`.`getUser`(1234567)
```

[this link](https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/12/23/solving-information_schema-slowness/) suggested to set `innodb_stats_on_metadata` to `0`, but didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `CheckedParameter=false` in the connection string to fix the issue.